# Converting SQL Query to remove window function from it

Tags: android, mysql, sql, android-room

Using Android Room library for local storage.
I have below query from the backend to implement it in Android app.

```
select DISTINCT timeStamp, batteryId, status 
from (select batteryDetails.*, 
             lag(status) over (partition by batteryId order by timeStamp) as oldStatus
      from batteryDetails) batteryDetails 
where status is null 
   or oldStatus <> status
```

By executing above query I am getting :

> error: no viable alternative at input '(select batteryDetails.*,
> lag(status) over (' public abstract java.lang.Object
> getHistoryEventsData(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Since we can not use Window functions using Room in Android,
i.e. Window function like which are used in above query : (lag etc.)

I have to remove it and have to make this query simple.
Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want the query to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `lag()` with a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct timeStamp, batteryId, status 
from (select bd.*, 
             (select bd2.status
              from batteryDetails bd2
              where bd2.batteryId = bd.batteryId
              order by timeStamp
              limit 1
             ) as oldStatus
      from batteryDetails bd
     ) bd 
where status is null or oldStatus <> status;
```